# Integration using CUDA kernels

Tags: numerical-integration, cudalink, cuda

I have never work with CUDA in Mathematica. My task connected with the calculation of a big amount of the same integrals. I have only 8 cores processor but my PC also has video processor with large amount of CUDA cores. I would like to launch calculation of the integrals on the CUDA cores use ParallelTable. Could you please demonstrate how to code this simple integral that Mathematica would compute using CUDA kernels.

```
P = NIntegrate[-a*(x - 5)^2 - 3 Sqrt[y] + Cos[x], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 3}];

ParallelTable[P, {a, {1, 3, 5}}]
```

Comment: Unless your problem can be rewritten in terms of a large ODE system, I would be very surprised if CUDA could be applied to it. If your problem _can_ be rewritten in terms of a large ODE system, you may also find that you no longer need CUDA to resolve it.

Comment: I don't understand you very well. My system contains integro-differential equations that depend on parameters.

Comment: Essentially, CUDA is not suitable for symbolic manipulations or generally problems that aren't embarassingly parallel. As far as I know, `NIntegrate` cannot be automatically translated into CUDA-friendly problems without manual intervention. Keep in mind that CUDA cores are not very tolerant of branching or any variety of flow control, so should not be directly compared to CPU cores.

Comment: Can Mathematica just calculate this integral using CUDA cores?

NIntegrate[-(x - 5)^2 - 3 Sqrt[y] + Cos[x], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 3}]

Comment: This would be nice to rewrite in CUDA. IT IS so SLOW! https://www.mathematica-journal.com/2017/10/20/an-algorithm-for-trigonometric-logarithmic-definite-integrals/